Arcpy- How do I add a list of data onto a boundary
I have created code that averages the yearly data and creates a list of lists, like so:
[['1988', 0.09680851063829785, 1.2444680851063827], ['1989', 0.2046808510638298, 1.0231914893617025]]

I want to append this data to the boundary that I have, but when I do so it only adds the first row of data.
How do I get this data appended to more rows?
# Add necessary fields if they don't already exist
if not arcpy.ListFields(outlayer, "YEAR"):
    arcpy.AddField_management(outlayer, "YEAR", "SHORT")
if not arcpy.ListFields(outlayer, "NITRATE"):
    arcpy.AddField_management(outlayer, "NITRATE", "FLOAT")
if not arcpy.ListFields(outlayer, "AMMONIA"):
    arcpy.AddField_management(outlayer, "AMMONIA", "FLOAT")

print(f"Processing boundary data for '{outlayer}'...")

# Update the feature layer with data from ndata
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(outlayer, ['YEAR', 'NITRATE', 'AMMONIA']) as cursor:
    for row, yearly_avg in zip(cursor, ndata):
        year_value = yearly_avg[0]
        no3_value = yearly_avg[1]
        nh4_value = yearly_avg[2]
        
        # Update cursor row with new values
        row[0] = year_value
        row[1] = no3_value
        row[2] = nh4_value
        
        # Update the row in the feature layer
        cursor.updateRow(row)


Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

what is cursor?  if it has only one element then zip() will create only one pair row, yearly_avg and you get only one item. And the same is with ndata - if it has only one element then zip() will create only one pair row, yearly_avg. If you want to use some element many times then maybe don't use zip()

arcpy.da.UpdateCursor only updates existing records, you'll need to use arcpy.da.InsertCursor to append new records: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/insertcursor-class.htm#C_GUID-DA74F0E0-2D67-472A-84B3-CB594A43750B

arcpy.da.UpdateCursor only updates existing records (see doc), use arcpy.da.InsertCursor to append new records (see doc).
Can't say for sure given the information provided (as furas commented, it would be helpful to debug more with some print statements), but the feature class you're trying to append to (outLayer) may only have one record/row to update.
